# Order of function evaluation and laziness

Tags: haskell

A bit of thinking about how "Laziness" and order of evaluation of a function

Consider this code :

```
testF x =  ((length x) >= 1) && ((head x) == "foo")

testG x =  ((head x) == "foo") && ((length x) >= 1)

testH x = False && ((head x) == "foo") 

testI x = ((head x) == "foo") && False
```

and the result of execution with an empty list

```
*Main> testF []
False
*Main> testG []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
*Main> testH []
False
*Main> testI []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Question concerning testF and testG : I read that Haskell evaluate leftmost outermost which would garantee the result; is it really a requirement of the language or is this testF [] evaluation is actually undefined behaviour ( for example in C++ it was the case until C++11).

Question concerning testH and testI : what seems obvious at first glance does not appear so obvious: even if it evaluates leftmost outermost, which garantee do we have than implementation does not perform some kind of reverse ordering evaluation:

Consider that:

```
myAnd _ False = False
myAnd False _ = False
myAnd a b = (&&) a b

testJ x =  myAnd ((head x) == "foo") False 
testK x =  myAnd False ((head x) == "foo")
```

gives reverted behaviour

```
*Main> testJ []
False
*Main> testK []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Finally, all the examples above make the (&&) operator failing regarding the commutativity law ( a&&b  == b&&a ), so I end up thinking that all those calls , ideally, should evaluate both arguments and raise an exception.

Comment: By the way, the third line of your `myAnd` function could (and should) just be `myAnd _ _ = True` instead of `myAnd a b = (&&) a b`.

Comment: in `tesK`, the "leftmost outermost" is your function `myAnd` which pattern matches against the second argument first. This forces evaluation of that term to check if it is false, causing your program to die.

Comment: Also, what exactly is your question here? You kind of say a lot of things, but I'm not 100% sure what the exact question you want answered is.

Comment: Just a side note, `&&` in C++ was always guaranteed-lazy; `testF` would be perfectly defined.

Comment: Re: commutativity, check out [`pand`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb-0.2.7/docs/Data-Unamb.html#v:pand). In particular we have `pand False undefined = pand undefined False = False` and `pand True undefined = pand undefined True = undefined`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Haskell doesn't evaluate the leftmost first for all cases. As you saw, this is due to your definitions. Take the definition of `&&`:

```
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
(&&) False _ = False
(&&) _ False = False
(&&) _ _     = True
```

Notice that it requires a pattern from the left argument first. This forces the left argument to be evaluated first, and could leave the second argument unevaluated. In your `myAnd` function, you switch the order of evaluation due to your pattern matching. If you swapped the 2nd and 3rd lines (which you did) the order of evaluation would also swap.

There is absolutely no undefined behaviour occuring here. Don't get your head stuck in C!

However, if a function pattern matches on two (or more) arguments, then it does evaluate the leftmost first. So, for example:

```
func1 True False = True -- Both arguments evaluated
func1 _ _        = False

test1 = func1 (error "leftmost") (error "rightmost")
-- Running test1 results in the error "leftmost"
```

Your point about commutativity is sharp. Technically, this does indeed not allow for the commutativity law. However, when reasoning about Haskell code we usually ignore bottom (`error` and `undefined` to non-mathematicians) for two reasons. One, it makes things nicer, and two, you shouldn't be encountering `error` anyway: that means that you've gone wrong. So in practice, no: `&&` is functionally commutative. `error`s should not be happening in your Haskell code, and there's no way to catch them for this reason; it breaks the nice algebraic properties as you pointed out. Use them only for events that should not occur, as in the implementation of `head`.

There are many other languages similar to Haskell, in particular Agda and Idris, which do away with `error` and `undefined` entirely for this reason, mostly because they have a specific goal of logical consistency, in order to be able to quite literally *prove* that your code is correct. However, Haskell (likely in a bid to stay more mainstream) does not do so.

Answer (score 9):

This behavior is guaranteed.

`||` and `&&` from Prelude [are defined to behave like this](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1710009) in Haskell 2010 section 9:

```
-- Boolean functions
(&&), (||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True && x = x
False && _ = False
True || _ = True
False || x = x
```

Pattern matching is also [defined to work left-to-right](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17) (3.17.2) with _ matching ⊥:

> Pattern
>       matching proceeds from left to right, and outside to inside, according to the following rules: [...] Matching the wildcard pattern _ against any value always succeeds, and no binding is done.

The same is true in the older Haskell 98 specification.